# Working with the latest PHP / MongoDB version

Tags: php, mongodb, wamp

After much of a struggle I managed to install MongoDB as a service and WAMP. Then on start I got a fatal error saying these would not work:

```
$m = new Mongo(...);
$m = new MongoClient(...);
```

In some previous questions on SO people mentioned using a new class called MongoDB/Driver/Manager. I also came across something called MongoDB/Client.

As a beginner to MongoDB I now stand rather confused about how to use/connect to a DB and collection.

I guess I will use:

```
$m = new MongoDB/Driver/Manager(...);
```

However,

```
$db = $m->$dbname; // Seems to cause -> Notice: Undefined Property
$collection = $db->shows; // dito
```

So all in all what are the difference between MongoDB/Driver/Manager and MongoDB/Client ? And with these new classes how would I correctly connect to a DB or Collection as shown in the previous snippet ? I can't seem to find many examples explaining how to use these new classes, or an up to date correct way of using the new classes for basic functionality.
Thanks,

Comment: My WAMP seems to allow me to use PHP 5.6.19 (default) or 7.0.4. I have the php-mongodb driver at version 1.1.8 (TS) x64 for both PHP versions.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what I am confusing.

Using the MongoDB/Driver/Manager class and others, are part of the basic tools available with the PHP MongoDB Driver. I am guessing it is not recommended using them unless you know what you are doing, or you want something relatively customized.

A more recommendable alternative is to install "mongodb/mongodb-^1.x.x" with a PHP installer such as Composer, which will give you a **MongoDB Library**. This will give you classes such as the `MongoDB/Client` class.

Once the library has been installed you can connect like so:

```
<?php 
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new MongoDB/Client('mongodb://localhost:27017');
// Add URI of MongoDB here
$mydb = $client->mydb; // Add the new DB name or existing DB name here
$collection = $mydb->createCollection('userCollection');
... 
?>
```

Comment: Still not quite sure what the MongoDB/Driver/ is for :P Or if you need the library to actually use MongoDB with PHP